# basic code debug python

Tags: python

I am a bit new in python, i tried to read similar example but i cannot find my answer.
I am just trying to return two values in my generator, one is the number and the other one is the timestamp. It works fine with just the number but i cannot "print" the timestamp, can someone please help me on this?

```
import random
import datetime

mynumber = 1000

def generator():
    i = 0
    while 1:
        yield random.randint(-1, 1)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        i = i + 1

for random_number in generator():
    mynumber = mynumber + random_number
    print mynumber
```

Comment: Please edit the question and paste a well indented code. You may also want to remove the commented / unused code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you want to do, but Python will allow you to `yield` and `return` multiple items (in the form of a tuple):

```
def generator():
    while 1:
        yield random.randint(-1, 1), datetime.datetime.now()

mynumber = 1000
for random_number, current_time in generator():
    mynumber += random_number
    print mynumber, current_time
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a static analysis thing for python that is good at spotting basic stuff

```
$ pyflakes f.py
f.py:10: local variable 'now' is assigned to but never used
```